# What is the recommended way for checking if the full-page-cache is enabled?

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.2, full-page-cache

How should I check **if enabled and then invalidate the Magento full page cache?**

I've found references that check if it is enabled using `Magento\PageCache\Model\Config->isEnabled()` and then invalidating it using `Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface->invalidate(Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER)`

The method `Magento\PageCache\Model\Config->isEnabled()` seems to be marked as deprecated.

**What would be the new recommended way?**